# Fitting an interpolating spline to show mean of interaction on cloud plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, lme4-nlme, scatterplot, interpolation

I am surprised to not be able to find a straight forward answer to my scenario. I have created a series of mixed effects models using lme4. I am trying to plot the data in `library(plotly)`, and want to include a surface showing the mean of two interacting variables. I understand I need to create a cubic interpolation spline, but I am unsure how to do so.

I first define my model of interest `M1`. To plot the interaction of fixed effects independent of random effects, I define `M0` and plot my interacting variables against `residuals(M0)`.

```
M1 <- lmer(delta.abundance ~ abundance:orig + (1|Site) + (1|Species), data = df)
M0 <- lmer(delta.abundance~ 1 + (1|Site) + (1|Species), data = df)
df$M0.resid <- residuals(M0)
plot_ly(df, x = ~abundance, y = ~M0.resid, z = ~orig)
```

This results in the plot below. Which is what I am after (somewhat).
[image: Plot]

However, I now want to draw a surface to indicate the mean of the interaction. I understand I need to create an interpolation spline, but after playing round and searching for a few hours I am at a loss.

Here is some of my data. The full dataset is of >4,000 rows.

```
structure(list(delta.abund = c(2L, -6L, 4L, -2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, -1L, 0L, -3L, 3L, 1L, -1L, 5L, 1L, -5L, -4L, -16L, 2L, -4L, 
-3L, -6L, -1L, -3L, 8L, -16L, -6L, -3L, -2L), abundance = c(16, 
41, 1, 4, 8, 2, 5, 9, 1, 3, 3, 29, 4, 14, 18, 1, 6, 22, 19, 15, 
8, 49, 13, 1, 3, 17, 24, 10, 9, 2), orig = c(17.88700681151, 
18.9288259169757, 18.4603116518462, 20.8332035259939, 16.7472469675955, 
14.0293953997288, 14.1036886542639, 11.0955567683252, 13.6588064253832, 
16.9010566483574, 16.9934316766242, 13.5158580800352, 15.5611635154033, 
17.5731559514392, 17.7166018446714, 17.0139328027606, 15.9536762115172, 
12.4298155146004, 11.3466300055911, 27.3228874943345, 17.9214336720829, 
12.6312757381688, 20.6027102669722, 19.5451066558618, 15.2834179510846, 
12.7871560505974, 14.3196493815345, 19.1251798722159, 18.9655787558725, 
15.5770204771959), M0.resid = c(3.89820236988076, -1.57881815478946, 
7.19958679418198, -1.23043232968725, 4.99670723018559, 1.60440547366629, 
-0.0324147190784339, -2.06025178278183, 0.311215710597539, 1.38033322794102, 
-0.630221516085614, 2.5726895466598, 3.47205589407126, 1.36025183508338, 
5.54958890746993, 1.47148560518279, -3.59710497975622, 0.504003033932483, 
-11.3191259926911, 3.5856998454695, -2.51669020054073, 1.86495177180049, 
-5.06717338727821, -0.39132197047688, 2.02215599325066, 8.11643893736162, 
-14.6261208998309, -3.52410943274074, 4.63844486776119, 5.37620656322495)),
.Names = c("delta.abund", "abundance", "orig", "M0.resid"),
row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```